# Customize WordPress pagination

Tags: wordpress, plugins, pagination

Good day, I am creating a plugin that will automatically posts a slideshow article with page break using `<!--nextpage-->` , my problem is i want to custom the pagination style instead of  page: 1,2 i want to show up as next-page and previous-page. how can i achieved this one? i want to put the code inside the plugin i don't want to add codes in the theme.

I have already tried adding this code in my plugin but did not work:

```
$defaults = array(
    'before'           => '<h1>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
    'after'            => '</h1>',
    'link_before'      => '',
    'link_after'       => '',
    'next_or_number'   => 'next',
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
    'pagelink'         => 'Page %',
    'echo'             => 1
);
wp_link_pages( $defaults );
```

This is the code in my plugin:

```
    $x = "";

 foreach ($leadamajig_data->questions as $post)
{

$lead_title =  '<p><h1 id="title">' . $post->title . '</a></h1></p>';
$lead_choices = '<p><h1 id="clicked"><a hre="#">' . $post->choices->a . '</a></h1></p>';
$lead_choices2 ='<p><h1 id="clicked2"><a hre="#">' .$post->choices->b . '</a></h1></p>';
$lead_choices3 = '<p><h1 id="clicked3"><a hre="#">' . $post->choices->c . '</a></h1></p>';

$x = $x . $lead_title . $lead_choices . $lead_choices2 . $lead_choices3 . '<!--nextpage-->';

}


$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => questions,
  'post_content'  => $x,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1
);

 wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 0):

`wp_link_pages()` returns the pagination markup you have defined with your `$default` array of parameters. So you probably already have the html that you want to show returned from the `wp_link_pages()` function.

Assign `wp_link_pages()` to a variable and then echo or print out the content where you want your pagination to appear.

Like this:

```
$defaults = array(
  'before'           => '<h1>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
  'after'            => '</h1>',
  'link_before'      => '',
  'link_after'       => '',
  'next_or_number'   => 'next',
  'separator'        => ' ',
  'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
  'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
  'pagelink'         => 'Page %',
  'echo'             => 1
);

$pagination = wp_link_pages( $defaults );

//Put this where you want your pagination to appear:
echo $pagination;
```

Comment: This is my post.

`<h1 id="title">What is the age of your dog?</h1>
<h1 id="clicked"><a>a.) 19 yrs. Old</a></h1>
<h1 id="clicked2"><a>b.) 29 yrs. Old</a></h1>

<!--nextpage-->
<h1 id="title">What is the color of your cat?</h1>
<h1 id="clicked"><a>a.) Red</a></h1>
<h1 id="clicked2"><a>b.) Brown</a></h1>

<!--nextpage-->`

this will result into: Page 1,2 

how will i transform that Page 1,2 into next and prev?